# What is the relation between ETIME and CPU_TIME?

Tags: performance, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to measure the performance of some Fortran code, currently this is done using [`ETIME`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ETIME.html) (essentially in the same way as the example in the docs). However, the `TIME` value does not seem to measure real time (it does not match the 'real' output of the UNIX utility `time`).

Is the [`CPU_TIME`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CPU_005fTIME.html#CPU_005fTIME) a better measure of the real execution time of a program? I thought `TIME` from `ETIME` would give the sum of user and system time, and should thus be the same or close to the real time (or `CPU_TIME`)?

The code does not fork any child processes.

Equivalent code below, based on examples from manual. Run with `time ./program`).

The real code writes to disk, and the real time (as reported by `time`) goes up if several individual processes are running at the same time. However, no change is detected in neither `ETIME` nor `CPU_TIME`.

The time reported by the real from `time` can be up to twice the time reported by `ETIME` or `CPU_TIME`.

```
  program test_etime
  integer(8) :: i, j
  real, dimension(2) :: tarray
  real :: result
  real :: start, finish

  ! 
  ! Comment out relevant part
  !

  print *, "TESTING ETIME"
  call ETIME(tarray, result)
  print *, result
  print *, tarray(1)
  print *, tarray(2)
  do i=1,100000000    ! Just a delay
      j = i * i - i
  end do
  call ETIME(tarray, result)
  print *, result
  print *, tarray(1)
  print *, tarray(2)


  !print *, "TESTING CPU_TIME"

  !call cpu_time(start)
  !do i=1,100000000    ! Just a delay
  !    j = i * i - i
  !end do
  !call cpu_time(finish)
  !print '("Time = ",f6.3," seconds.")',finish-start

  end program test_etime
```

(sneaking in a last one; why is the `CALL ETIME (...)` syntax recommended?)

Comment: Can you give an example, ie. a valid minimal program, the timings you get from UNIX `time` and the output as given by your `ETIME` call? This would give people an idea of how different your timings are between the two methods.

Comment: It is tricky to write a small problem to test this since it involves running several processes using the disk at the same time to actual produce anything that does not match the reported `real` time. I suspect what I want is `SYSTEM_CLOCK`, I somehow expected it to be what I got from `TIME` in `ETIME`.

Comment: When I run your example, I find ETIME reports a total of `0.7029s` whilst time reports `real: 0.713s; user : 0.702s;  sys: 0.002s`. So summing `user` and `sys` we get something just a little over what ETIME reports. Note that the real time doesn't equal the sum of user and sys. This indicates the process got less than 100% utilisation of a cpu -- this could presumably occur if the proc is waiting for I/O?

Comment: It may also be worth noting that some shells (such as bash) provide their own version of time -- you might want to check running with `/usr/bin/time ./program`

Comment: Yeah - the example doesn't really get to the issue since the real case involves lots of disk and processes competing for resources.

Answer (score 0):

This has bean treated here several times, just without the stress on ETIME.

Standard Fortran does NOT know any ETIME. It is an extension supplied by your compiler and you have to read the manual of your compiler to find out what it does. It can vary between compilers.

In the manual they state quite clearly what ETIME does for gfortran. If you think there is a problem, well, you should show us your results first!

CPU_TIME measures the CPU time which is the sum of the CPU times spent for all threads! It can be several times more than the real time spent executing the program for parallel programs.

**For wall-clock time measurement use the standard `SYSTEM_CLOCK()`. Or some people (not me) prefer `omp_get_wtime()` and `MPI_Wtime()` instead if you use OpenMP and MPI. The results should be identical up to the measurement uncertainty.**

There can still be a small difference from the OS reported `real` time of course! What it measures is the wall clock time spent between two points in the programs. but don't forget there is some time spent before your code starts executing and after your code starts executing. There is initialization and finalization of the program run involved.

---

Why is call ETIME recommended? Who knows for sure, but impure functions are not nice. Functions should ideally return the same answer for the same input. And this clearly doesn't.

There is a very similar problems in pseudorandom generators. They should really be subroutines, not functions.

Comment: It is not irrelevant to fortran just because the function is compiler specific, a compiler is an integral part to making a fortran program. The output of `TIME` from `ETIME` does not match the `real` field reported from the `time` UNIX utility.

Comment: I haven't said it is irrelevant to Fortran. I have said you should show the results. Where are they?

Comment: Right - some of your paragraphs mentions what standard Fortran does - which seems irrelevant. Results are not easy to show since the issues do not arise before several processes are run at the same time, writing to disk. For the same reason it is not easy to make a simple example program. As you mention, I probably need SYSTEM_CLOCK.

Comment: Theoretically, TIME() should return a similar result, at least for gfortran. I don't know the reason for the difference. It mentions exactly one description of what standard Fortran does. I can't see that irrelevant by any means.

Comment: By the way; if you think there are problems or missing information with my question - which I can certainly agree to. I'd prefer to be told in a nice way: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice.

Comment: If you ignore the nicer way, then we make you somehow notice the request... Hence the bold script and capital letters. You have high enough reputation to know how to ask at this site.

Comment: Fortran standard is relevant when you ask about Fortran and not about a specific compiler. System_clock is best with int64 arguments but with some Windows compilers omp or mpi timers may be better.